# Reledmac/Reledpar: unnumbered familiar footnotes

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, reledpar

I'd like to be able insert familiar footnotes in reledmac/reledpar (specifically, within ledgroups) that will generate text within the apparatus but will not make a footnotemark in the edited text.

(My goal is to produce the equivalent of a manuscript apparatus as in critical notes, but without any line or paragraph numbering, since it will be clear that it refers only to that particular ledgroup.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[parledgroup]{reledpar}

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
This is the main edited text, in the left column.\footnote{And     footnotes for this text appear at the bottom of the whole page.}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{ledgroup}
This is text from manuscript A and some other sources\footnoteA{sources ] manuscripts B} that explain\footnoteA{explain ] clarify C} the text in the lefthand column\footnoteA{column ] portion D}. I'd like to list all the manuscripts on which this text is based (ABCDEFG) at the beginning of the paragraph of familiar footnoteAs, but without giving this information its own numbered footnote.
\end{ledgroup}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to produce the equivalent of a manuscript apparatus as in
>   critical notes, but without any line or paragraph numbering, since it
>   will be clear that it refers only to that particular ledgroup

That is the most important thing. You can configure reledmac to not print any number in critical footnotes. You must use both `\Xnonumber` and `\Xinplaceofnumber`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[parledgroup]{reledpar}

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xnonumber
\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
This is the main edited text, in the left column.\footnote{And     footnotes for this text appear at the bottom of the whole page.}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{ledgroup}
This is text from manuscript A and some other \edtext{sources}{\Afootnote{manuscripts B}} that \edtext{explain}{\Afootnote{clarify C}} the text in the lefthand \edtext{column}{\Afootnote{portion D}}. I'd like to list all the manuscripts on which this text is based (ABCDEFG) at the beginning of the paragraph of familiar footnoteAs, but without giving this information its own numbered footnote.
\end{ledgroup}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

In invite you to look on all the options explained on § 7 of reledmac handbook.

Ps:
For your problem of apparatus manuscriptum, you could use what is explained on § 6.4 of reledmac handbook. However, I am not sur it would work in ledgroup. The more easy way is to:
1. Use level B of footnote for variant
2. Use level A of footnote for list of manuscripts
3. Use a empty critical footnotes without lemma separator
4. Set to print nospace when not using lemma separator (`\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}`)

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[parledgroup]{reledpar}

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xnonumber
\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
This is the main edited text, in the left column.\footnote{And     footnotes for this text appear at the bottom of the whole page.}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{ledgroup}
\edtext{}{\Afootnote[nosep]{Your manuscript list}}
This is text from manuscript A and some other \edtext{sources}{\Bfootnote{manuscripts B}} that \edtext{explain}{\Bfootnote{clarify C}} the text in the lefthand \edtext{column}{\Bfootnote{portion D}}. I'd like to list all the manuscripts on which this text is based (ABCDEFG) at the beginning of the paragraph of familiar footnoteAs, but without giving this information its own numbered footnote.
\end{ledgroup}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: A simpler way to get the same result as this solution is just to use \footnotetext inside the ledgroup. It prints an unnumbered footnote above the numbered familiar footnotes.

Comment: Or, perhaps most straightforward, just to use \skipnumbering to have an unnumbered line at the bottom of the ledgroup itself. I did study section 7 with some care! But it only applies to critical footnotes, not the familiar footnotes that I need. What I had hoped to find was something like \inplaceofnumberX for the first footnote.

Comment: the use of not numbered critical footnotes is, I think, the most safe solution, as it is fully conceived for this need.

Comment: hi, Jesse, any news?

Comment: Hi, Maïeul! Thanks for asking. I actually came up with a satisfactory work-around by putting my apparatus of manuscripts at the *top* of each block of ledgroup text. It's now a kind of title instead of part of the footnotes, which is perfectly acceptable for my purposes. Example image: <img src="https://medrefchurch.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/reledpar-example.jpg" width="100" height="100"> But in the future, would you be willing to consider adding functionality for \footnoteAtext, \footnoteBtext, etc.? It would be extremely useful to have that capacity within reledmac's familiar footnotes.

Comment: Thanks, Maïeul. I found an acceptable workaround by giving the MS apparatus as part of the title of each ledgroup. This is fine for my purposes. (Sample image here: https://medrefchurch.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/reledpar-example.jpg)

Comment: sorry, but I still don't understand your need, and why you are not able to do with all the actual tools of reledmac…

Comment: In any case, if you need new feature, you must open a github issue…

Comment: Thanks, Maïeul. Sorry for not explaining myself clearly. My need is to be able to insert notes in the familiar footnotes (\footnoteA, etc.) that do not have footnotemarks in the main text, but which appear continuously with the numbered familiar footnotes (particularly, in the same paragraph of footnotes when paragraph layout is enabled). I will open a github issue and try to be more precise. It seems to me that the existing options, which are excellent, will only work for critical notes (\Afootnote, etc.), which are not appropriate for my project. Thanks again!

Comment: Hum, yes, I think a github issue with a precise description (especially, an model of the attempting output) will be useful.